# Post-receive hook for gitosis

Tags: git, hook, gitosis, git-post-receive

I'm running `Gitosis` and want my committed work to be staged in my html directory.

I was trying to use [this](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) approach to set GIT_WORKING_TREE to my html directory, but I'm getting the error `remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`. I think it's because Gitosis seems to necessitate bare-repositories.

Any advice will be a great help.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this exact same issue here. We have the following in a `post-receive` hook

```
echo "Updating pages"
unset GIT_DIR GIT_WORK_TREE
( cd /path/to/staging/tree ; git pull ; )
echo "Update completed"
```

If Git sees either of those environment variables when you tell it to `pull`, it will get confused, and not look in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a post-receive hook to cd to a non-bare repository with a working tree and execute a pull there after you've pushed to the bare repo.

In general, it's best to push to bare repositories and pull to repos with working trees.